# Kendo UI - Place Command Toolbar at bottom of grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

In certain areas of my application, it is more user friendly to have custom commands within the grid command toolbar be at the bottom of the grid instead of the top.

I was wondering if this was possible within Kendo UI or if there was some other work around for it.

Below is the code for a standard read-only BUT selectable grid.

Thanks in advance!

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("AddressBookGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(i => i.IsOrigin).ClientTemplate("<input name='Origin' id='origin' type='radio' value='Origin' />").Width(70);
    columns.Bound(i => i.IsDestination).ClientTemplate("<input name='Destination' id='destination' type='radio' value='Destination' />").Width(70);
    columns.Bound(i => i.CompanyName).Width(120).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "CompanyName" });
    columns.Bound(i => i.AddressLine1).Width(150).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "AddressLine1" });
    columns.Bound(i => i.AddressLine2).Width(150).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "AddressLine2" });
    columns.Bound(i => i.City).Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "City" });
    columns.Bound(i => i.StateProvince).Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "StateProvince" });
    columns.Bound(i => i.PostalCode).Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "PostalCode" });
    columns.Bound(i => i.CountryCode).Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "CountryCode" });
})
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    //Want to place this at the bottom
    toolbar.Custom().Text("Add").Url("#_").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "PopulateAddressForm()" });
})
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
.Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(false)
)
```

)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, this is not supported out of the box. Can be done with the following line of code:

```
$("#grid").find(".k-grid-toolbar").insertAfter($("#grid .k-grid-content"));
```

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/ahifiz/2/edit

Comment: Thanks so much!  Had this exact question posted on the Kendo forums for over a week, and you got to it less than a day!  Since I needed this for multiple grids, I made a generic function that passes in the grid name.  Thanks for the quick and great reply!

Comment: function MoveCommandBar(gridName) {
   $("#" + gridName.toString()).find(".k- grid-toolbar").insertAfter($("#" + gridName.toString() + " .k-grid-content"));
}

Comment: How about when using angular js? I have the same issue.

Comment: I changed the insertAfter to insertBefore, and then changed k-grid-content to k-grid-pager.  This put the toolbar just above the pager on my grid.  :)

Comment: I was stuck with this for a while, and found out later that in my case, `.k-grid-content` didn't exists, so I had to change it to a different class within the grid. Then this worked again.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to the Angular question, I created a directive to do the same thing. It currently checks for the paging control and moves the toolbar after that, or if the pager doesn't exist, after the grid content.

```
[YourApp].directive("toolbarOnBottom", ["$timeout",
    function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    element.find(".k-grid-toolbar").insertAfter(element.find(".k-grid-pager").length === 1 ? element.find(".k-grid-pager") : element.find(".k-grid-content"));
                }, 1);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```